# How to check if an array of objects contains all the ids of another array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, verification

I have 2 arrays of Objects;

```js
// First one :
[0: {id: 1},
1: {id: 2},
2: {id: 3},
3: {id: 4}]

// Second one :
[0: {id: 10},
1: {id: 1},
2: {id: 4},
3: {id: 76},
4: {id: 2},
5: {id: 47},
6: {id: 3}]
```

I'd like to test if the second one has at least every same IDs of the first one. Which would be true in this case because the second one contains 1, 2, 3 and 4 IDs.

I tried to use some() and every() but it doesn't work properly

My try :

```
let res = this.trainingEpisodesList.some( episode => {
    this.completedEpisodes.every( userEpisode => {
         userEpisode.id == episode.id;
     })
});
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: *but it doesn't work properly* is not an error description. What is your expectation and what is the output of your code?

Comment: Not returning anything inside of a `some` or `every` call is one reason, why your try won't do what you want. I'd also get a better IDE/linter (or configure them properly), a statement like `userEpisode.id == episode.id;` should be automatically marked as "probably a mistake".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let completedEpisodes = 
[
{id: 1},
{id: 2},
{id: 3},
{id: 4}
]

let trainingEpisodesList = 
[
{id: 10},
{id: 1},
{id: 4},
{id: 76},
{id: 2},
{id: 47},
{id: 3}
]

let containsAllCompleted = trainingEpisodesList.every(c => completedEpisodes.find(e=>e.id==c.id));

console.log(containsAllCompleted);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, it just returns false as it should returns true.

I'd like to have TRUE if the completedEpisodes contains every trainingEpisodesList's IDs

Comment: @LuDo if the example above is correct for you, then reversing the arrays in the operation should fix it. I updated the answer. The answer now checks if all training episodes are completed

Comment: Thank you very much dude, could you explain a bit what this combination of methods do please ? I have read the documentation but it's still not that clear :(

Comment: Sure. So the objective of the question was to check if all items in ``trainingEpisodesList`` are in ``completedEpisodes`` given the ``id`` as the identifier. The two used functions are ``every`` which checks if all items of an array match a certain condition, and ``find`` which checks if there is an item in an array with a specific ``id``. So, what we should do is check if ``every`` item in the training episodes list matches our condition which is being present in the completed list (using ``find``).

Comment: Sounds logic,  was too much lost in readings to get it through. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

ES7,

```
let result = one.map(a => a.id);
let result2 = two.map(a => a.id);
const final_result = result.every(val => result2.includes(val));
```

ES5,

```
var result = one.map(a => a.id);
var result2 = two.map(a => a.id);

var final_result = result.every(function(val) {

  return result2.indexOf(val) >= 0;

});
```